# Getting the error message: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

Tags: jquery, html, json

I've come across this error message in the console of my browser "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null".

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

```js
//create a new XMLHttpRequest object
var myXhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

//function will be called when the state of the request changes
myXhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState === 4) {
        if (this.status === 200) {
            //single JSON 
            var film = JSON.parse(myXhr.responseText);
            var output = "";
            output += "<h1>" + film.title + "</h1>";
            output += "<p>" + film.director + "</p>";
            var contentDiv = document.getElementById("content");
            contentDiv.innerHTML = output;
        } else {
            alert("Something went wrong.");
        }
    }
}

//specify the resource we want to access
myXhr.open("get", "index.json", true);

//makes the request
myXhr.send(null);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Page</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
    
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page">
 
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>My Title</h1>
        </div><!-- /header -->
 
        <div data-role="content">
            <p>Hello world</p>
        </div>
        <!-- /content -->
      
              <div data-role="footer">
            <h4>My Footer</h4>
        </div><!-- /footer -->
 
    </div><!-- /page -->
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html
```

I've also made a JSON file with the below data:

```
[
    {
        "title": "Jaws",
        "year": "1975",
        "director": "Steven Spielberg"
    },
    {
        "title": "Mean Streets",
        "year": "1973",
        "director": "Martin Scorcese"
    },
    {
        "title": "Forrest Gump",
        "year": "1994",
        "director": "Robert Zemeckis"
    }
]
```

Comment: where's `DIV` with the `id` of `content`

Comment: Ahhh yes, I didn't notice I miss that out! Thank you very much Amit! It is now working... I knew there was something really obvious I missed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because this `content` element does not exist in the DOM, so it results in `null` so what you can do is add the ***id*** *attribute* to your div:

```
<div data-role="content" id='content'>
```